# How do I install midi controller drivers and Traktor Pro software?

Tags: drivers, sound, midi

I want to use ubuntu budgie remix 16.10, I'm dj and I have a MIDI controller that controls a sofware, called traktor pro. I use the controller in windows 7 ulltimate without problem, but I want to use it in ubuntu.

My problems are as follows:

1. How to install the driver from my controller (Xponent from the manufacturer m-audio) in Ubuntu? Knowing that there is only driver for windows 7.
2. How to install the program that the controller controls, the traktor pro (native instruments company)? Knowing that the installer is for Windows.

Thank you very much for the help and attention of all. I am available to try to do this remotely via teamviewer if necessary.

Comment: Do you tried contact the manufacturer customer service/support?

Answer (score 0):

You can't install the Windows drivers. And you can't install Traktor Pro windows version on Linux. What you can try is mixxx.org, a free DJ program, much like Traktor.

Comment: Unfortunately, the mixxx is a software much inferior to the traktor, would not have how to install everything by wine?

Comment: The best place to run windows-software is under Windows .. Wine might work for some software, but not all. If you can't find your software on a wine supported list, you just have to try to install it.